# Android - Firebase auth's signInWithEmailAndPassword error is: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do a simple log-in using email and password. Even if I log-in with the correct email and password, I get an error saying "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password".

Here is my code:

```
email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email)).getText().toString().trim();

password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password)).getText().toString().trim();

Log.i(TAG, "username : ["+ email +"]");
Log.i(TAG, "password : ["+ password+"]");

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                     FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                     // ...
                 }else {
                     Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                     // ...
                 }
              }
        });
}
```

My current firebase auth dependency is 19.1.0

The email and password logs are appearing correctly.

Firebase auth is not null.

Email and password sign-in method is enabled.

The AndroidManifest contains Internet permission.

The Internet is on during log-in.

The passwords are not "12345" or "abcde".

Any help will be appreciated, and I can add more details.

EDIT: It worked when I made a new project and transferred the parts one by one. I think removing the "android gms play services auth" dependency did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is because the email address and password you enter are not what Firebase has stored.

It's impossible to say from your question how you got into this state, but given the error message it is extremely likely that your understanding of the email/password combination is not matching what is stored in Firebase.

You can either [send a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) from the Android app, or use an Admin SDK to [change the user's password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have already sent the password reset email and updated it accordingly, and it still does not work when I enter the correct password.